# How to fetch all properties of calendar folder using EWS in C#

Tags: exchangewebservices

We are using Exchange Web Service (EWS) API in our C# application to fetch the calendar processing configurations provided by the following commands. 
Get-CalendarProcessing

Code snippet used in our application is

```
var ewsUserConfiguration = UserConfiguration.Bind(Exchangeservice, "Calendar", CalendarFolderId, UserConfigurationProperties.Dictionary)
```

However, this fetches only changed properties of the mailbox in the Dictionary, but not all the properties.

Example: If we had changed the property of DeleteSubject using the command in the Exchange management shell console
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity mail-room1 -DeleteSubject $false
then the dictionary will only have the "DeleteSubject" configuration returned.

How to get all the 35 configurations under Get-CalendarProcessing using EWS APIs in our application?

We do not want to PowerShell invocation in our code but to get all properties through EWS.

Answer (score 0):

What that EWS operation does is returned the contents of the Folder Associated Item in question. The other properties your referring to haven't been set so don't exist in the underlying data stream so therefore they won't appear when you make a request. If a property is not set they you can assume that its will be using the default value.